# How to export physics data from Blender 2.80 now that BGE is gone?

Tags: export, add-on, physics, rigidbody

The add-on I used ("blender-bullet-export") worked enough to export rigid bodies from the scene into a .bullet file, but it relies on BGE.

Now that BGE is gone (for good) in Blender 2.80, what can we do to export physics data or .bullet files, and why there is no UI option or builtin available format after all those years.

Comment: I poked around to try and find information on the serialization format, but it looks like the [wiki page](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Bullet_binary_serialization) even [this pdf](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/docs/Bullet_User_Manual.pdf) links to is gone. I'm curious, what are you using bullet serialization for?

Comment: I use the same Bullet Physics library API, so it is easy to import the rigid bodies in bullet with the .bullet file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can answer my own question.

After some digging I found another simple add-on compatible with Blender 2.8 (this time called "bullet-blender-exporter", LOL) that exports a .json instead of a serialized .bullet file. A nice work-around for anyone that needs to export quickly the rigid bodies and constraints from Blender.

For anyone interested the add-on is this: https://github.com/xu-xionglong/bullet-blender-exporter